# How to avoid 2 times api auth when design api structure

Tags: api, architecture

PS: the 3 system can be seen as 3 micro service connected by HTTP restful api.

As the img shown below:

Now the situation is:

When the api usage is 1 (which is outer api user invoke account system when api auth has passed),

And when the api usage is 2,3 (which is outer api user invoke business system when api auth has passed),

And when the api usage is 4,5 (which is inner business system invoke account system when api auth has passed)

This 3 usage is all fine.

But when the api usage is 2,3,4,5 (which is outer api user invoke business system when api auth has passed, but business system has to call account system to accomplish the function.)

This api usage has to do api auth 2 times, which I think make things complicated.

The requirement is that both outer api user and inner system must pass api auth when they invoke business system or account system.

Can anyone tell me how to do the auth more simpler?

Thank You!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Provide a separate auth server and teach all the business-services you've mentioned to talk to it. That's quite common when it comes down to a rather complicated microservices architecture.

Then you could easily share the same JWT (BTW, does not matter: whatever you prefer) with any number of (micro)services.